# How to scope data in express / node controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I'm trying to avoid callback hell by breaking down my Express / Kraken.js controller into smaller callback functions.

I was processing a request and had about 6 levels of nested anonymous callback functions.

so now I have my main function that looks like this:

```
// ugh, I know this isn't right
var globalProducts = {};

module.exports = function (server) {

    server.get('/project', function (req, res) {
        var data = req.query;
        globalData = data; 

        if(!data.projectId || !data.ruleSetId) 
            res.json({error: "Incomplete input data."});

             // pass response to products call back 
        Project.findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data.projectId) }, setUpProducts);   
    });
};

function setUpProducts(err, project){
    // get all products and pass them down the pipe
    project.findAllChildren(setUpRules);
}

function setUpRules(err, products) {
    // we need to access products in another function 
    globalProducts = products; 
    // find the rule set and build the rule Flow
    RuleSet.findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(globalData.ruleSetId) }, function(err, ruleSet) { 
        ruleSet.buildFlow(processFlow);
    });
}
```

My question is what is the best way to pass around info between callbacks ? My solution was `var globalProducts = {};` but to me, the controller contain any 'global state' .. whats the best way to handle this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this is a bad idea. It will cause race condition type issue — basically it's the same as sharing data in multithreaded environment. Instead you can use `req` or `res` to store data. To do that you need them in scope, so you can define all functions inside route handler or make each function a middleware so it will have `req` and `res` as arguments. Here is an example of this approach:

```
function check (req, res, next) {
  if(!req.query.projectId || !req.query.ruleSetId) return res.json({error: "Incomplete input data."});  
  next()
}

function findProject (req, res, next) {
  Project.findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.projectId) }, after);  

  function after (err, project) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    req.project = project;
    next();
  }
}

function findProducts (req, res, next) {
   req.project.findAllChildren(after)

  function after (err, products) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    req.products = products;
    next();
  }
}

function respond (req, res) {
  res.render('view', {
    products : req.products,
    project : req.project
  });
}


module.exports = function (server) {
   server.get('/project', check, findProject, findProducts, respond);
};
```

Comment: FYI. I'm attaching 'globals' to res.locals .. ie. res.locals.products according to http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals

Comment: It's also a good way to go if you a going to use it in the view